# IOredis Connection is Closed error in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

IOredis Connection is Closed error in Nodejs. We are using ioredis npm, When we are trying to getting the data from redis, we are getting "Connection is Closed" errors.

Actually, in calling the hnormalget() function is giving Connection is Closed error.

```
var redis = require('ioredis');
var config = require('./../../config');
var redisConfig = config.database;
var clientRead = Promise.promisifyAll(redis.createClient({
    port: config.database.redisPort,
    host: config.database.redisHost,
    prefix: config.database.redisPrefix,
    password: config.database.redisPassword,
    connectionName: 'redisDB-gpRedisCacheRead',
    db:10,
    readOnly: true,
    keepAlive: 1,
    retryStrategy : function retryStrategy(times) {
        log.error("Redis retry strategy called for gpRedisCache.js...44")
        if (typeof times != "number") {
            // Manual Reconnect would be require
            // redis.connect()
            return new Error('Redis Retry time exhausted');
        }
        const delay = Math.min(times * 50, 2000);
        return delay;
    }
}));

    var DBNUM = config.redis.GPDatabaseNum;
    clientRead.on('connect', function() {
        clientRead.select(DBNUM, function(e, r) {
            if (e) {
                log.error(`Error in redis Read select db server/lib/gpRedisCache.js: ${e}`);
                clientRead.end(true); //also initiate reconnection
            } else {
                // console.log('clientRead connected');
            }

        });
    }); //end of client.on('connect')

    clientRead.on('error', function(err) {
        log.error(`Error in redis connection on file gpRedisCache.js:95: ${err}`);
        clientRead.end(true); //also initiate reconnection here
    });




var redisCacheSeparateReadWritePooledConn = {
    hnormalget: (hashKey, key, cb) => {
        return clientRead.hget(hashKey, key).then((data) => {
            return { err: null, data };
        }).catch(err => {
            return { err };
        });
    },
}

//TILL above is the handling for single conn
module.exports = redisCacheSeparateReadWritePooledConn;
```

Comment: Your `clientRead` variable is a Promise. You need to wait for it to resolve, either with `.then()` or `await`, before you use the object it wraps.

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you so much for the reply, actually, my server got start successfully and I got redis connection. But when I am making a call for getting the data from redis through  hnormalget() function, it gives error "Connection is Closed".

Comment: @O.Jones I have tried the same and seems working fine, Thanks for the help.